# Why do Java class file versions start from 45?

Tags: java, jvm

According to the JVM specification:

> Oracle's Java Virtual Machine implementation in JDK release 1.0.2 supports class file format versions 45.0 through 45.3 inclusive. JDK releases 1.1.* support class file format versions in the range 45.0 through 45.65535 inclusive. For k ≥ 2, JDK release 1.k supports class file format versions in the range 45.0 through 44+k.0 inclusive.
>
> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html

I'm wondering, why did they start versioning from ***45*** and not, say, from ***1*** or ***0***?

Comment: probably the same reason as why `magic` number is `0xCAFEBABE` .... "coffee, baby"!? xDxD  ... humorous engineers!?  and 45 particularly is close to 42 ....

Comment: - > https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file ! ;)    "...JDK 1.1 = 45 (0x2D hex).
For details of earlier version numbers see [footnote 1 at The JavaTM Virtual Machine Specification 2nd edition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se6/html/ClassFile.doc.html) ..."

Comment: @xerx593 this does not explain _why_, though.

Comment: I can hint into the direction of "one-oh-one" because `45` is `101 101`? But I have no idea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why do Java class file versions start from 45?

There were versions of Java before the first publicly released version (Java 1.0.2).

Java originally started life as the [Oak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oak_(programming_language)) programming language in 1991.  It was renamed as Java in 1994 and the first public release was in 1996.

It is safe to assume that classfile versions less than 45 were used for earlier (pre-release) versions of Java and probably Oak.  In the early days, it is likely that the developers made numerous changes to the bytecode instruction set and other aspects of the classfile format. That would have required "bumping" the classfile version number on a regular basis.

The above is largely conjecture.  There is very little publicly available information on Oak and pre-1.0 Java.  However, the text of the [Oak specification](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/%7Ewaldo/oakSpec.pdf) from 1993 indicates that they were *already* compiling Oak source code to bytecodes that were stored in ".class" files, one per class.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to make the most sense. Oak specification is a treasure, I didn't even know it existed.